# print more than one output for a particular condition in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print both(or more than one) the outputs if the output comes out to be same from a list on separate lines
example->There are  students in this class whose names and grades are assembled to build the following list:

```
python students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
```

The lowest grade of  belongs to Tina. The second lowest grade of  belongs to both Harry and Berry.
There are two second lowest,so we order their names alphabetically and print each name on a new line.

Comment: Where is your printing code? What output are you getting and what do you want instead? Show samples.

Comment: @bhucho, can you provide an example of your output?

Comment: could you please rephrase the question specifying what you did so far, what are you trying to archive and an example of the expected result?

Comment: Please also show your attempts to print, and the desired output. For more details, check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 aspects to this question:

1. To sort by each sublist value, use `sorted` with a custom function.
2. To print on separate lines, you can use a `for` loop.

Here's an example:

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2],
            ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]

for name, val in sorted(students, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])):
    print(name, val)

Tina 37.2
Berry 37.21
Harry 37.21
Harsh 39
Akriti 41
```

If you want score ordering highest to lowest and keep names alphabetical for a tie-breaker, you can use `sorted(students, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the list of lists `students` then assemble a dictionary to print the values.

```
print_dict = {}
for name, score in students:
    if score in print_dict:
        print_dict[score] += [name]
    else:
        print_dict[score] = [name]
```

Once you have the dictionary of values to print you could print by iterating and sorting:

```
for score, names in print_dict.items():
    print score, ', '.join(sorted(names))

Out:
    41 Akriti
    37.2 Tina
    37.21 Berry,Harry
    39 Harsh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet to produce the output in the expected format.

```
import operator
    students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
    students_sorted = sorted(students, key=operator.itemgetter(1,0))
    print('\n'.join(' '.join(map(str,sl)) for sl in students_sorted))
```